# testing powermock simulate http server time out for client call

Tags: java, mockito, powermock

i need to write testcase for connectTimeout and SocketTimeout exception. Am using powerMock to create mock objects. Below is my code. But am getting null pointer exception for my mock objects. Any help appreciated

```
package com.util;
import java.net.ConnectException;
import java.net.SocketTimeoutException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PowerMockIgnore;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.SuppressStaticInitializationFor;
import org.powermock.modules.testng.PowerMockObjectFactory;
import org.powermock.modules.testng.PowerMockTestCase;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.IObjectFactory;
import org.testng.annotations.ObjectFactory;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

@PowerMockIgnore("javax.management.*")
@SuppressStaticInitializationFor("com.Sender")
@PrepareForTest(Sender.class) 
public class SenderCatalogTest extends PowerMockTestCase{


@ObjectFactory
public IObjectFactory getObjectFactory() {
  return new PowerMockObjectFactory();
}
@Test
public void testSocketExceptionEvents() throws Exception{
    String url="https://www.google.co.in/";
    URL mockURL = PowerMockito.mock(URL.class);
    PowerMockito.whenNew(URL.class).withArguments(url).thenReturn(mockURL);
   SocketTimeoutException expectedException = new SocketTimeoutException();
   PowerMockito.when(mockURL.openConnection()).thenThrow(expectedException);
    Sender sender = new Sender();
    String input="{\"level\":3,\"event\":{\"name\":\"myevent\",\"Address\":\"xyz\"}}";
    JSONObject vent = new JSONObject(input);
    Assert.assertNotNull(sender.send(vent));
```

Please find for the logs

```
at com.Sender.send(Sender.java:81)
at com.SenderCatalogTest.timeout(SenderCatalogTest.java:33)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:68)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:316)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:88)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:96)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:300)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:131)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.access$100(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:59)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner$TestExecutorStatement.evaluate(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:147)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.evaluateStatement(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:107)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:288)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:86)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:208)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:147)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:121)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:33)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:45)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:123)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:121)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
2016-08-19 12:49:34,107 main ERROR Could not reconfigure JMX java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/powermock/core/classloader/MockClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "javax/management/MBeanServer"
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadUnmockedClass(MockClassLoader.java:250)
at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadModifiedClass(MockClassLoader.java:194)
at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:71)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.jmx.Server.unregisterAllMatching(Server.java:328)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.jmx.Server.unregisterLoggerContext(Server.java:250)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.jmx.Server.reregisterMBeansAfterReconfigure(Server.java:162)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.jmx.Server.reregisterMBeansAfterReconfigure(Server.java:138)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:502)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:561)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:577)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:212)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:152)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:45)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:194)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getContext(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:103)
at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:43)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:42)
at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:29)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:329)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:349)
at com.SenderUtil.<clinit>(SenderUtil.java:17)
at com.SAEventSender.<clinit>(SASender.java:15)
at com.Sender.send(Sender.java:148)
at com.SenderCatalogTest.timeout(SenderCatalogTest.java:33)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:68)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:316)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:88)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:96)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:300)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:131)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.access$100(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:59)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner$TestExecutorStatement.evaluate(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:147)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.evaluateStatement(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:107)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:288)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:86)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:208)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:147)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:121)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:33)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:45)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:123)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:121)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)

2016-08-19 12:49:34,182 main ERROR Could not reconfigure JMX java.lang.LinkageError: javax/management/MBeanServer
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.jmx.Server.unregisterAllMatching(Server.java:328)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.jmx.Server.unregisterLoggerContext(Server.java:250)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.jmx.Server.reregisterMBeansAfterReconfigure(Server.java:162)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.jmx.Server.reregisterMBeansAfterReconfigure(Server.java:138)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:502)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:561)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:577)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:212)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:152)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:45)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:155)
at com.SenderUtil.initLogger(SenderUtil.java:64)
at com.SenderUtil.<clinit>(SenderUtil.java:18)
at com.SAEventSender.<clinit>(SASender.java:15)
at com.Sender.send(Sender.java:148)
at com.SenderCatalogTest.timeout(SenderCatalogTest.java:33)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:68)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:316)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:88)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:96)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:300)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:131)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.access$100(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:59)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner$TestExecutorStatement.evaluate(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:147)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.evaluateStatement(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:107)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:288)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:86)
at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:208)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:147)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:121)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:33)
at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:45)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:123)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:121)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)

2016-08-19 12:49:34,616 pool-1-thread-1 ERROR Caught exception executing shutdown hook Shutdown callback for LoggerContext[name=6842775d] java.lang.LinkageError: javax/management/MBeanServer
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.jmx.Server.unregisterAllMatching(Server.java:328)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.jmx.Server.unregisterLoggerContext(Server.java:250)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.jmx.Server.unregisterLoggerContext(Server.java:237)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.stop(LoggerContext.java:295)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext$1.run(LoggerContext.java:260)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.DefaultShutdownCallbackRegistry$RegisteredCancellable.run(DefaultShutdownCallbackRegistry.java:102)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.DefaultShutdownCallbackRegistry.run(DefaultShutdownCallbackRegistry.java:72)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2016-08-19 12:49:34,620 pool-1-thread-1 ERROR Caught exception executing shutdown hook Shutdown callback for LoggerContext[name=Default] java.lang.LinkageError: javax/management/MBeanServer
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.jmx.Server.unregisterAllMatching(Server.java:328)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.jmx.Server.unregisterLoggerContext(Server.java:250)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.jmx.Server.unregisterLoggerContext(Server.java:237)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.stop(LoggerContext.java:295)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext$1.run(LoggerContext.java:260)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.DefaultShutdownCallbackRegistry$RegisteredCancellable.run(DefaultShutdownCallbackRegistry.java:102)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.DefaultShutdownCallbackRegistry.run(DefaultShutdownCallbackRegistry.java:72)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Below is my Sender class send method

```
public String send(JSONObject vent) throws IOException{
    String method;
    int level;
    HttpsURLConnection conn = null;

    try {

        URL obj = new URL(url);
        conn = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();// line number 81
        conn.setRequestMethod(method);
        initializeURL(conn);
        ....
        }
        catch(SocketException e){
        }
        catch(ConnectException e){
        }
```

Comment: Could you please paste your stack trace here, that would be more specific to analyse and helps to answer.

Comment: @KumarMekala It would also be helpful if you post the code of `Sender` class, especially `send()` method, and point to the line 81 (where NPE happens)

Comment: @noscreenname i have added sender class. and also mentioned code for line number 81

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at [wiremock](http://wiremock.org/docs/simulating-faults/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i was able to solve it. Incase some gets the same issue again. In my code  issue was withArguments line. I was trying to pass

String url="https://www.google.co.in/";

as the Url parameter. But in the actual it was null.

URL mockURL = PowerMockito.mock(URL.class);
PowerMockito.whenNew(URL.class).withArguments(url).thenReturn(mockURL);

withArguments try to match if the parameters are same. On having same url paramter on my mock and actual object in code i was able to proceed with out null pointer exception

Answer (score 0):

Acording to [powermock documentation](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/MockConstructor), in the section mock constructor, you should be doing something like that:

```
URL mockURL = PowerMockito.mock(URL.class);
expectNew(File.class, url).andReturn(mockURL);
replay(mockURL, File.class);
```

Also, be sure to use annotations `@PrepareForTest(Sender.class)` and `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)`

Comment: i don't see those methods available as mentioned in documents. And yes am using `@PrepareForTest(Sender.class) and @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)` annotations

Comment: @RK3 it's part of easymock library

Comment: can't it be done with Powermock. Why should i use easymock?

Comment: @RK3 easymock is part of powermock, it simplifies the syntax. I haven't been able to find working static mock examples with something other than easymock. I really advise you to take a look at the documentation of the library that you are attempting to use.

Comment: one more thing  want to mention is that my other 55 test cases are running on grizzly server. I added this new test class and grizzly server shutdown before this test case runs.

Comment: @RK3 I don't know what to do with that information. Maybe you should ask another question